# How to Select Query with "as" and Join Table in SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm about to create query `select join` with `sqlalchemy` like:

```sql
SELECT position.*, device.name as devicename
FROM `position` JOIN `device`
ON position.id_device = device.id
ORDER BY position.id_device
```

So in python file, I create the query like the following:

```
result = sql.query(Position, Device).\
            join(Device, Position.id_device == Device.id).\
            order_by(Position.id_device).first()
```

I got the result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "size": "600x300",
    "price": 150,
    "id_category": 0,
    "id_device": 1,
    "impression": 9999,
    "status": 1,
    "name": "Home Top Banner",
    "id_website": 1
  },
  {
    "deleted_at": null,
    "status": 1,
    "name": "Desktop",
    "id": 1
  }
]
```

The result that i want as the `mysql` query above is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "size": "600x300",
    "price": 150,
    "id_category": 0,
    "id_device": 1,
    "impression": 9999,
    "status": 1,
    "name": "Home Top Banner",
    "id_website": 1,
    "devicename": "Desktop",
  }
]
```

The main code flow:

```
[...]
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()
[...]

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

def db_session() -> Generator:
    """
    Get database connection with DI (Dependencies Injection)
    """
    try:
        dbsession = SessionLocal()
        yield dbsession
    finally:
        dbsession.close()
    
@router.get('/{ad_type}')
def ad_unit(
        ad_type: str,
        sql: Session = Depends(db_session)
):
    """Display ads unit of the available product"""
    result = get_position(sql, ad_type=ad_type)
    return result
    [...]    

def get_position(sql: Session, ad_type: str):
    result = sql.query(Position, Device).\
              join(Device, Position.id_device == Device.id).\
              order_by(Position.id_device).first()
    [...]
```

Model classes:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql

from app.settings.mysql_settings import Base


class Position(Base):
    """A class used to represent position table (ads price list & dimensions)"""
    __tablename__ = 'position'

    id = Column(mysql.INTEGER(display_width=11, unsigned=True), primary_key=True,
                index=True, autoincrement=True)
    id_device = Column(mysql.INTEGER(display_width=11), nullable=True)
    id_website = Column(mysql.INTEGER(display_width=11), nullable=True)
    id_category = Column(mysql.INTEGER(display_width=11), nullable=True)
    name = Column(mysql.VARCHAR(length=50, collation="utf8_unicode_ci"), nullable=True)
    price = Column(mysql.INTEGER(display_width=11), nullable=True)
    status = Column(mysql.TINYINT(display_width=1), nullable=True, default=1)
    size = Column(mysql.TEXT(collation="utf8_unicode_ci"), nullable=True)
    impression = Column(mysql.DOUBLE(), nullable=False, default=0)


class Device(Base):
    """A class used to represent a list of device type for ads unit e.g: Mobile, Desktop, etc."""
    __tablename__ = 'device'

    id = Column(mysql.INTEGER(display_width=11), primary_key=True,
                index=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(mysql.VARCHAR(length=50, collation="latin1_swedish_ci"), nullable=True)
    status = Column(mysql.TINYINT(display_width=1), nullable=True, default=1)
    deleted_at = Column(mysql.TIMESTAMP(), nullable=True)
```

I've tried many ways to get the result that I want, by merge/union the result and others but it doesn't work. I think there's a specific way to get the result that I want with `sqlalchemy` but I cannot found it in the doc because there are so many references.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: One – hacky – way that depends on how you serialize to JSON (not included in your question) would be to `query(Position.__table__, Device.name.label('devicename'))`.

Comment: i got an array `[
  1,
  1,
  1,
  0,
  "Home Top Banner",
  150,
  1,
  "600x300",
  9999,
  "Desktop"
]` instead of a single array of object

Comment: That's your JSON encoder treating the result object as a tuple (which it is, in a way). If you add a step where you convert the [row proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy) to a list of dict, it'll come out as you want. So `result = [dict(result)]`, for example.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're right, I'll to figure it out later

Comment: @metaphor If I look at [the examples here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join), it seems you should not have included `Device` twice. Try this: `sql.query(Position).join(Device, Position.id_device == Device.id).order_by(Position.id_device).first()`

Comment: @MikeWilliamson well actually, that query absolutely works, but I only get the result from `Position` table, the result that I want is like the example I've provided above, only one little thing that i really want which is to insert an alias column from `Device` table: `device.name as devicename` into the result

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally found the answer, I've tried so many ways and you know what `print` save my day :D

So, I found 2 solutions here, and both of it is work like want I want. The first one is still using the ORM style, and the second one by doing the `raw` query

```
j = join(Position, Device, Position.id_device == Device.id)
stmt = select([Position, Device.name.label('devicename')]).select_from(j)
result = sql.execute(stmt)
return result.fetchall()

# or by raw query
result = sql.execute("""SELECT position.*, device.name as devicename
    FROM `position`
    JOIN `device` on position.id_device = device.id
    ORDER BY position.id_device""")
return result.fetchall()
```

That's it. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To translate a query like this:

```
SELECT users.name AS users_name,
        addresses_1.email_address AS addresses_1_email_address,
        addresses_2.email_address AS addresses_2_email_address
FROM users JOIN addresses AS addresses_1
        ON users.id = addresses_1.user_id
JOIN addresses AS addresses_2
        ON users.id = addresses_2.user_id
WHERE addresses_1.email_address = ?
        AND addresses_2.email_address = ?
('jack@google.com', 'j25@yahoo.com')
```

the equivalent SQL alchemy syntax is this:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
>>> adalias1 = aliased(Address)
>>> adalias2 = aliased(Address)
SQL>>> for username, email1, email2 in \
...     session.query(User.name, adalias1.email_address, adalias2.email_address).\
...     join(User.addresses.of_type(adalias1)).\
...     join(User.addresses.of_type(adalias2)).\
...     filter(adalias1.email_address=='jack@google.com').\
...     filter(adalias2.email_address=='j25@yahoo.com'):
...     print(username, email1, email2)
```